# Multipage Post URL correction

Tags: posts, url-rewriting, urls, nextpage

I freshly installed WordPress and checked for multipage post, which is separated by `<!--nextpage-->`.

I'm expecting first URL should be:

```
example.com/wordpress/this-is-test/1/
example.com/wordpress/this-is-test/2/
and so on...
```

But when I use `example.com/wordpress/this-is-test/1/`, it automatically redirect to `example.com/wordpress/this-is-test/`.

How can I keep the `/1/` at the end?

Comment: yes it's possible. One has to modify the canonical redirect via the `canonical_redirect` filter. Then there are some adjustments needed via the filters of `wp_link_pages()`.

Comment: Thanks @birgire. Can you provide me simple example please?

Comment: Please show some research and what you've tried so far and explain where you stopped. Thanks

Comment: @birgire I have tried to catch `canonical_redirect` url using:
`add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', array( $this, 'filter_canonical' ), 19, 2 );`
try to get and print `redirect_url` from args and `exit()`
but it redirected without `exit()`

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation isn't right. Numbers are only added to pages 2 & higher. The first page retains the single page's slug.

Comment: Thanks Andy,but I am going to display all the content of the page when we don't have numbers at the end. If numbers at the end I'll display that page content.

Comment: Ah. A subtle English distinction. Sorry :-)